# Member "xxx" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in type

Tags: struct, modifiers

How can I access to fields of struct that is in mapping from different contract?

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Contract1 {
    struct User {
        bool isValid;
        uint value;
    }

    mapping(address => User) public party;  
}

contract Contract2 {
    Contract1 c1;
       constructor (address addr) {
       c1 = Contract1(addr);
}

modifier requireDeposit(address _eventAddress) {
    require(c1.party(_eventAddress).isValid, "Not a valid user!");
    _;
}

}
```

I get **`TypeError: Member "isValid" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in tuple(bool,uint256).`** error.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access the struct field directly. But you can do:

```
modifier requireDeposit(address _eventAddress) {
    (isValid,) = c1.party(_auctionAdress);
    require(isValid == true, "Not a valid user!");
    _;
}
```

`c1.party(_auctionAdress)` returns the fields of Contract1 where `,` is just a place holder for a `value` field, since you dont need it.